# Need to remove a bunch of white space on PDFs?

Tags: pdf, formatting, pdf-generation, acrobat

I have around 100 PDF files (each 1-3 pages long) that are formatted strangely, and I need to fix them. The problem is that there's a ton of white space at the top of almost all of them. I have Acrobat X Pro.

For example: http://imageshack.us/a/img195/510/ex1w.png
Download example: http://www.sendspace.com/file/2hohj5

I've tried selecting the text with the "Move or make changes to objects tool" and shifting it up, but there's a white box in the way that covers the text. If I delete the box, there's more text under it that I can't have.

I'm very confused. If this question isn't making sense please download the pdf and try for yourself.

Another example (across multiple pages this time): http://imageshack.us/a/img337/3714/ex2v.png 
Download example: http://www.sendspace.com/file/q7dmnl

Comment: So how much of the whitespace you want to remove? Which output format do you want for the modified file? Should it remain PDF or should it be transformed into an image format (such as JPEG, PNG, TIFF...)?

Comment: You really are not very clear what your goal is with these pages: Which way do you need to "fix" them? Crop away the "white" space and reduce the page dimensions? Shift the visible content into the center of each page? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry! To clarify: I want the output to remain a PDF file. All I would like to do is shift all of the content upwards so that there isn't an absurd amount of whitespace. Around 1 inch would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ghostscript to cut off content from pages and reduce the page height. Try this:

```
gs                  \
  -o out.pdf        \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -g6120x5000       \
   2hohj5.pdf
```

Result of 1st page cropped (as PNG, scaled down):

[image: out.png]

Alternatively, you can use Ghostscript to shift the contents of each page up by, say 3 inches ( == 216 points) without changing the page sizes:

```
gs                                                  \
  -o out2.pdf                                       \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite                                 \
  -c "<</Install {0 216 translate}>> setpagedevice" \
  -f 2hohj5.pdf
```

Result of 1st page, content shifted upward by 3 inches (scaled PNG):

[image: out2.png]

Comment: This sounds like the ideal solution. So one more question... How in the world do I run a Ghostscript? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please check my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690094/how-to-remove-top-white-space-from-pdf